# Transfer files to a portable media device

Tags: windows-7, mp3-player

I have a sony walkman and I am making a music manager to make so it would be able to sync to the device. i have tried to go into the storage device and have found that the path is: Computer\WALKMAN\Storage Media\MUSIC. I have tried the dos command: `copy "Song.mp3" "WALKMAN\Storage Media\MUSIC"`. but i get the error :

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

What is the path to this portable media device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it uses/is in UMS mode, there isn't one. You'll need to find a MTP client, if one exists.

Comment: No it dint work. It turns out its MTP. If windows can do it then there must be a command to do the transfer

Comment: @P'sao can you post the answer here?

Comment: I ended up just changing drivers for the me3 player so it acted like a mass storage device.